# How can I populate a choice box with an array of objects in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, awt, box

I have a choice box in my GUI

```
Choice choice = new Choice();
choice.setBounds(75, 11, 93, 20);
panel.add(choice);
```

I also have this array of objects:

```
public Planet[] planetList;
```

every

> Planet

has a name field. I'd like to populate the choice box with my planetList and display the name field, so when the users choice the planet by name, it selects the Object Planet that has that name.

If it's easier, I could use a combobox or whatever I could use as a dropdown list of my array.

Comment: Assuming we are talking about https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Choice.html based from example shown there you can use `choice.add(nameOfPlanet)`. So if your Planet class lets you get its name you should be able to do something like `for (Planet p : planetList){ choice.add(p.getName()); }`.

Answer (score 0):

To create `java.awt.Choice`:

```
Choice fruitChoice = new Choice();
```

To fill in the choices:

```
  fruitChoice.add("Apple");
  fruitChoice.add("Grapes");
  fruitChoice.add("Mango");
  fruitChoice.add("Peer");
```

To get the selected item:

```
String fruit = fruitChoice.getItem(fruitChoice.getSelectedIndex());
```

Comment: It can be `String fruit = fruitChoice.getSelectedItem();`